# Inject EJB into RESTeasy webservice

Tags: java, resteasy, wildfly

Im currently having a problem injecting a `@Stateless`-EJB into my RESTeasy implemented webservice:

Resource:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/rest/events")
public class EventResource
{
@EJB
EventService eventService;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAllEvents()
{
    System.out.println(eventService);
    return Response.ok().build();
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("{id}")
public Response getEventById(@PathParam("id") String id)
{
    System.out.println(id);
    int intId = Integer.parseInt(id);
    Event e = eventService.getById(intId);
    System.out.println(e);
    return Response.ok(e).build();
}
```

Service:

```
@Stateless
public class EventService
{
...
}
```

Application:

```
public class SalomeApplication extends Application
{
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet();

    public SalomeApplication()
    {
        this.singletons.add(new EventResource());
    }

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        return this.empty;
    }

    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    {
        return this.singletons;
    }
}
```

I'm using `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.0.11.Final`, `Wildfly` and application server. I also tried using `Inject` and `RequestScoped` instead - doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance of `EventResource` is created by you and as you are not setting the `EventService` reference it must of course be `null`.
You are also registering this instance as Singleton so you'll always get exactly this instance.

If you add `EventResource.class` to the Set of classes RESTeasy will take care of creating the instances and managing the dependencies. If you prefer to use Singletons you should use the auto-scan feature. On Wildfly this is enabled by default so all you need to do is remove the content of your `SalomeApplication`.